# Getting labels/names and invert wikidata query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'am trying to get the names of the victims, which got a "stolperstein" (stumblestone) in my hometown. But I can't get the names with `SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }`

I think, the query should be

```
SELECT ?Stolperstein ?StolpersteinLabel ?bild ?Person ?tod WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Stolperstein wdt:P31 wd:Q26703203;
    wdt:P131 wd:Q2107;
                SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
                wdt:P547 ?Person.
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

My second question is, how can I display the data with missing information. (invert the query / like `NOT IN`)

```
SELECT ?Stolperstein ?StolpersteinLabel ?bild ?Person ?tod WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Stolperstein wdt:P31 wd:Q26703203;
    wdt:P131 wd:Q2107;
                wdt:P547 ?Person.
                ?Person wdt:P570 ?tod
```

gives me only 88 results, but there are 188 "stones", so therefore in 100 datasets is the information date of death (P570) missing.

Comment: the first query is invalid syntax and you have the label SERVICE twice. Please fix it. Same for the second query

Comment: and getting the names for the persons is the same you did for the "Stolpersteine" - add another variable `?PersonLabel`

Comment: regarding the 2. question: do you want to get all "Stolpersteine" where not date of death is known?

Comment: That query returns all person with the date of death is known: `SELECT ?Stolperstein ?StolpersteinLabel ?bild ?Person ?PersonLabel ?todesDatum WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Stolperstein wdt:P31 wd:Q26703203;
    wdt:P131 wd:Q2107;
    wdt:P547 ?Person.
  OPTIONAL {?Person wdt:P570 ?todesDatum}
  }`

Comment: for all persons without a death date it is: `SELECT ?Stolperstein ?StolpersteinLabel ?bild ?Person ?PersonLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Stolperstein wdt:P31 wd:Q26703203;
    wdt:P131 wd:Q2107;
    wdt:P547 ?Person.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?Person wdt:P570 ?todesDatum}
  }`

Comment: Unfortunaly, i am unable to vote up your answer...
Thanks!